# Testing code for RACE scenarios

Tags: html, database

We have a condition in which we need to test for a RACE condition. Right now, we are having three developers click submit at the same time. While not super scientific, it has worked for what we are trying to test for but we wonder if there is a better, more reliable way to test this. Saying out loud, "1, 2, 3, click" is subject to user error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You basically need to setup some type of listener for the event you are triggering. Then you would need to log the timestamp of when the event was triggered. You would also want to trace which user triggered the event to compile some useful comparison data.

You don't provide much info about the technology being used so that's about as specific as I can be.

Comment: Thanks - the company wont allow us to post too specific details on an open forum so I can't list any more details but you make a very good case I hadn't thought about and will work just fine for what we need to test. Thanks for the idea!